# websphere unable to deploy server

Tags: websphere

I have created a profile using the manageprofiles.sh command as
./manageprofiles.sh -create -profileName OMK -profilePath "${WS_HOME}/profiles/AppSrvOMK" -templatePath "${WS_HOME}/profileTemplates/default" -nodeName AppSrv01Node -cellName AppSrv01NodeCell -omitAction samplesInstallAndConfig defaultAppDeployAndConfig

To deploy it/ to see the server onto the admin console what do I need to do

Pls let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a profile which looks like a stand alone. A default server - "server1" should be created for you.

If this is the first profile you are creating the ports should be the default ones.

http://:9060/ibm/console

should be your admin console.

I would look at the logs first and see if the profile creation is completed. If yes, go to the profiles bin directory and issue serverstatus -all.

This should list server1 for you.

Issue startserver server1 to start your server and once it is started visit the admin console URL and you are ready to go.

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Hi,
In WAS 5, we used to create a server from Admin Console by servers->application serevers-> application server and then "add new server" functionality

After the introduction of profiles, the "add new server" from admin console is not there

So, how do I achieve the same thing in WAS 7 ND. i.e creating a new server in the same node/cell

Thanks